# Como realizar mock em uma classe?

Tags: php, phpunit

Criei esse script para fim de testes, e tenho uma classe `Calculadora` que recebe como parâmetro uma instancia da  classe `Operacao`, quando realizo o teste unitário passando a classe o teste ocorre com sucesso.

Porém ao substituir a classe `Operacao` por um `mock` recebo um erro 
***informando que a classe não é do tipo desejada***. Como fazer para passar um `mock` dessa classe?

Calculadora.php

```
<?php

namespace Application;
use Application\operacao;

class Calculadora
{
    private $num;
    private $num2;
    private $operacao;
    private $resul; 

    public function __construct(operacao $operacao, int $num, int $num2)
    {   
        $this->operacao = $operacao;
        $this->num  = $num;
        $this->num2 = $num2;
    }

    public function Somar()
    {
        return $this->num + $this->num2;
    }

}
```

operacao.php

```
namespace Application;

class operacao
{

    private $operacao;

    public function __construct(String $opc)
    {
        $this->operacao = $opc;
    }


    public function getOperacao()
    {
        return $this->operacao;
    }
}
```

PHPTest

```
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as PHPUnit;
use Application\Calculadora;

use Application\operacao;


class PHPTest extends PHPUnit
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->opc = $this->getMockBuilder('operacao')
                  ->getMock();
        //$this->opc = new operacao('Soma');
        $this->Calculadora = new Calculadora($this->opc, 1 , 2);
    }


    public function tearDown()
    {

    }

    public function testOperacaoMatematica()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(3, $this->Calculadora->Somar());
    }
}
```

Mesmo após efetuar as mudanças ocorreu o seguinte :[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu fiz um exemplo minimo dê uma olhada @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou chamar o método `->getMock();`, como [especificado nesse link tutorial](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/).

***Exemplo:***

```
$opc = "string";
$this->opc = $this->getMockBuilder('operacao')
                  ->setConstructorArgs([$opc])
                  ->getMock();

$this->Calculadora = new Calculadora($this->opc, 1 , 2);
```

---

***Exemplo Minimo:***

***Classes:***

```
<?php namespace Application;

class operacao
{
    private $operacao;
    public function __construct(string $opc)
    {
        $this->operacao = $opc;
    }

    public function getOperacao()
    {
        return $this->operacao;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php namespace Application;

class calculadora
{
    private $operacao;
    public function __construct(operacao $operacao)
    {   
        $this->operacao = $operacao;
    }
    public function somar(int $num1, int $num2): int
    {
        return ($num1 + $num2);
    }
    public function subtrair(int $num1, int $num2): int
    {
        return ($num1 - $num2);
    }
}
```

---

***Classe de teste:***

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";
require "t1.php";
require "t2.php";

class PHPTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    protected $calculadora;
    protected $opc;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->opc = $this->getMockBuilder(\Application\operacao::class)
            ->setConstructorArgs([""])
            ->getMock();

        $this->calculadora = $this->getMockBuilder(\Application\calculadora::class)
            ->setConstructorArgs([$this->opc])
            ->setMethods(null)
            ->getMock();

    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
    }

    public function testOperacaoMatematicaSomaEquals()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(4, $this->calculadora->somar(2,2));
    }

    public function testOperacaoMatematicaSomaNotEquals()
    {
        $this->assertNotEquals(1, $this->calculadora->somar(2,2));
    }

    public function testOperacaoMatematicaSubtrairEquals()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(-1, $this->calculadora->subtrair(1,2));
    }

    public function testOperacaoMatematicaSubtrairNotEquals()
    {
        $this->assertNotEquals(1, $this->calculadora->subtrair(1,2));
    }
}
```

**Teste:**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O teste foi desenvolvido em PHP versão 7.0 e passou nos 4 testes e as configurações do `Mock` estão corretas.

***Referencia:***

- [Unit Testing Tutorial Part V: Mock Methods and Overriding Constructors](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-5-mock-methods-and-overriding-constructors/)
- [What is the difference between createMock and getMockBuilder in phpUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363086/what-is-the-difference-between-createmock-and-getmockbuilder-in-phpunit)
- [PHPUnit API reference](https://gist.github.com/loonies/1255249)

Comment: já tinha tentado com o "getMock", igual ta aqui na documentação : https://phpunit.de/manual/current/pt_br/test-doubles.html ! porém sem sucesso. Quanto a segunda tratativa o método "createMock" está sendo acusado como indefinido :/.

Comment: ao realizar do primeiro jeito recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro "__construct() must be an instance of Application\operacao, instance of Mock_operacao_11020db9 given"

Comment: Talvez @DavidSantos o erro é superior a essas duas linhas, se tem como colocar as duas classes na sua pergunta ???

Comment: o código ta bem tosco, mas tudo bem.

Comment: A sua classe operacao tem construtor com parâmetro deve ser isso eu fiz uma edição dá uma olhada?

Comment: então, efetuei a mudança e o resultado foi : ReflectionException: Class Mock_operacao_d23b9f26 does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor arguments

Comment: talvez tenha algo relacionado com a versão desatualizada, estou usando a 3.7, vou atualizar!

Comment: @DavidSantos eu escrevi novamente o método é um pouco diferente a coisa quando é com Mock!

Comment: efetuei as mudanças conforme vc postou, na verdade copiei e colei o código, porém não resolveu, postei um print

Comment: @DavidSantos eu fiz o exemplo, mudei código você realmente copiou na integra? Eu to achando que é um problema pontual...

Comment: só ficou diferente as minhas importações na classe teste, mas o resto eu copiei tudo.

Comment: @DavidSantos o problema me parece local!

Comment: é você estava certo, após refazer tudo o teste funcionou, muito obrigado!