# Como realizar mock da classe, sem passar por parâmetro

Tags: php, phpunit

Usando PHPUnit consigo mockar uma classe e passar por parâmetro e testar um método é caso do `selectById`. Porém não estou conseguindo mockar `Acesso` e testar `pessoaLogadaIgualPessoaAtividade`.

Como fazer o teste de `Pessoa->pessoaLogadaIgualPessoaAtividade`?

```php
class Pessoa
{
    private $dao = null;
    public function setDao($dao)
    {
        $this->dao = $dao;
    }    
    public function selectById( $id )
    {
        $result = $this->dao->selectById( $id );
        return $result;
    }
    public function pessoaLogadaIgualPessoaAtividade( $idPessoaAtividade ){
        $result = false;
        $controllerAcesso = new Acesso();
        $idPessoaLogada = $controllerAcesso->getUserId();   
        if( $idPessoaLogada == $idPessoaAtividade) {
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Para o teste estou tentando fazer:

```php
    public function testPessoaLogadaIgualPessoaAtividade_true()
    {
        $mock = $this->createMock(Acesso::class);
        $mock->method('getUserId')->willReturn(1);

        $pessoa = new Pessoa();

        $expected = true;
        $result = $pessoa->pessoaLogadaIgualPessoaAtividade(1);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }
```

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213000/como-realizar-mock-em-uma-classe) me ajudou para fazer o teste do `selectById`.

Comment: se criar o objeto do tipo `Acesso` dentro da classe vai ser impossível de fazer o mock, precisa usar *injeção de dependência* para poder fazer o mock e testar, basicamente precisar receber por parametro o tipo `Acesso`, assim: `public function pessoaLogadaIgualPessoaAtividade( $idPessoaAtividade, Acesso $controllerAcesso ){`.
Não consigo escrever uma resposta detalhada agora, mas se seguir essa outra resposta do SO acho que vai entender: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18564335/4730201  Se ainda tiver dúvida, deixe um comentário que assim que puder coloco um exemplo mais explicativo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe algumas formas de fazer isso.

Já que o PHPUnit usa classes de testes para cria-las, logo você pode usar o convencional paradigma de orientação a objetos criando um **constructor** para sua classe e fazer a injeções de dependencias necessarias para ela e depois apenas acesse-las por atributos, nao se esquecendo que objetos privados não são enxergados fora da própria classe.

Por exemplo:

```
private $id
```

Se voce tem um id privado e queira que esse objeto propage para os metodos do PHP unit voce tem que fazer o correcto encapsulamento dele usando:

```
public function setId($id = null)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getId(): int // espera-se que o seu ID seja um integer ,caso contrário so mudar o tipo de retorno.
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

[Este artigo aqui é bem detalhado explicando.](https://www.theaveragedev.com/injecting-mocks-into-type-hinted-parameters/)

Eu espero ter ajudado e principalmente entedido claramente o que voce gostaria de fazer, caso contrário por favor me de mais detalhes que será um prazer ajuda-lo.